# I cannot step into the imported function from the Python module using the PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, function, debugging, module, pycharm

I have my main Python script that uses the function 'hello_world' from my imported module 'module1.py

[image]

However, if I use the PyCharm Debugger I cannot step into the 'hello_world' function.

I am following these steps:

1. Execute 'main.py' in debug mode
2. Set break point in function 'hello_word'

[image]

3. Press 'Step Into' from Debug window: "Frame not available"

[image]

4. After all the previous steps, it Goes back to main.

[image]

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

PyCharm: 2023.2.1 (Community Edition)
Python: 3.8

Step into 'hello__world' function, but it did not work.

Comment: What happened instead?

Comment: It says frame not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had my source files in a mapped drive, and the file path contained non-conventional characters, such as spaces. Removing the special characters from the path resolved the issue.